# How to Scrape reviews with read more from Webpages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reviews from a website and am not able to scrape reviews having a **'read more'** option.
I am only able to get data till read more.
I am using BeautifulSoup.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the click option given with selenium that will allow you to find the read more tag or class and click it, as soon as it appear you will have to click it again.. and when it does not shows up you will have to scrap the content you require,

Comment: can you please explain what is click option in bs4 and how to use it?

Comment: @user5444075 my mistake I was talking about selenium...bs4 doesn't support clicking. you should atleast post your code or the website you are trying to scrap so that someone can help you

Comment: I tried getting the link, 'read more' was pointing to I got an <a> tag with an onclick attribute. Can't I use that to expand the review?

Comment: @user5444075 buddy you need to study selenium a bit, documentation has clear guidance on how to find element of your interest and by different options by id or class. click the tag if it is clickable. [documentation-selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

Comment: I did some research on selenium and found out that selenium may be very slow..is that true

Comment: @user5444075, If you can parse the links of reviews and make another request then it is fairly easy to do. It will be better if you reveal the link of that site, so that you may get quicker response.

Comment: The website I wanna scrape reviews from is somewhat like this http://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Lakeside-Chalet-Mumbai-reviews-925017044 Do you mean that I need to make another request

Comment: What I meant is: first you make a request to pull the link of that "view more" option then make another http request with that newly populated link and then you will find yourself there where you wanna go. FYI, if there is any option for click, you can be sure that there is a link. Hope you got me now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of how you can get the full text of all the reviews. Run it and get the results. Wait a while after execution. This is how you can do without clicking on any link.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Lakeside-Chalet-Mumbai-reviews-925017044").text, "html.parser")
for title in soup.select("a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_]"):
    items = title.get('href')
    if items:
        broth = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(items).text, "html.parser")
        for item in broth.select("div.user-review p.lnhgt"):
            print(item.text)
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried this code and it worked, now from my understanding you first request the website, then instead of using 'read more' search the link of the title of the review, request the link by getting its 'href', store it in broth and lastly search the review and loop through its paragraphs (Correct me if I'm wrong). Two things that are bothering me, one when printing title I get the full link with a# excluded (why is that?) and where'd you get "div.user-review p" from (I know it's in the link we access but where in that page.)

Comment: Do inspect element of the below page where you will find ["div.user-review p"] http://www.mouthshut.com/review/Lakeside-Chalet-Mumbai-review-mlmqulpsq btw, I made second request using the link extracted from "Peace, Quiet, and What a View!".

Comment: Also I tried your code and couldn't find why the review is being printed 2 times. I also inspected the page and did not find any redundancies. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: Your main question was how can you get to the full review by manipulating read more option with the help of BeautifulSoup. I tried to show you how you can. Perhaps you missed the line under my answer where I've written explicitly that it is not optimized yet but will give you an idea about the process. Thanks.

Comment: Try the updated code. I've edited that to serve your purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@user5444075 and @SIM

```
div.user-review p.lnhgt
```

The above does not seem to exist anymore.

The below xpath can be used to get all the href.

```
//a[contains(@id,"lnkTitle")]/@href
```

Make a new request to the server using the above href and get the text of the class rev-main-content