# Python 3 BeautifulSoup Scraping Content After "Read More" Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've recently started looking into purchasing some land, and I'm writing a little app to help me organize details in Jira/Confluence to help me keep track of who I've talked to and what I talked to them about in regards to each parcel of land individually.

So, I wrote this little scraper for landwatch(dot)com:

[`url` is just a listing on the website]

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_property_data(url):
    headers = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # Maybe request Url with read more already gone
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
    title = soup.find_all(class_='b442a')[0].text
    details = soup.find_all('p', class_='d19de')
    price = soup.find_all('div', class_='_260f0')[0].text
    deets = []
    for i in range(len(details)):
        if details[i].text != '':
            deets.append(details[i].text)
    detail = ''
    for i in deets:
        detail += '<p>' + i + '</p>'
    return [title, detail, price]
```

Everything works great except that the class `d19de` has a ton of values hidden behind the `Read More` button.

While Googling away at this, I discovered [How to Scrape reviews with read more from Webpages using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735733/how-to-scrape-reviews-with-read-more-from-webpages-using-beautifulsoup), however I either don't understand what they're doing well enough to implement it, or this just doesn't work anymore:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Lakeside-Chalet-Mumbai-reviews-925017044").text, "html.parser")
for title in soup.select("a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_]"):
    items = title.get('href')
    if items:
        broth = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(items).text, "html.parser")
        for item in broth.select("div.user-review p.lnhgt"):
            print(item.text)
```

Any thoughts on how to bypass that `Read More` button? I'm really hoping to do this in BeautifulSoup, and not selenium.

Here's an example URL for testing: `https://www.landwatch.com/huerfano-county-colorado-recreational-property-for-sale/pid/410454403`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is present within a `script` tag. Here is an example of extracting that content, parsing with `json`, and outputting land description info as a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json

url = 'https://www.landwatch.com/huerfano-county-colorado-recreational-property-for-sale/pid/410454403'
headers = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # Maybe request Url with read more already gone
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')

all_data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').string)
details = all_data['description'].split('\r\r')
```

---

You may wish to examine what else is in that `script` tag:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(all_data)
```